# Warning when connecting to MongoDB: "warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, eventemitter

I'm having a problem with the Event Emitter warning in Node.js. I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using [Mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin). Could you please explain to me why the warning is occurring and how to avoid it?

```
for (j in self.channel_data) {
            ( function( channel, index ) {

                mongo.collection('revenue_share')
                    .find({ approved: true,
                            entity_id: channel.user_channel_id,
                            date_effective: {$lte: +new Date(self.report_data[channel.report_id].end_date).getTime()}
                        }, selectables)
                    .sort({date_effective : -1})
                    .toArray(function (err, _data) {

                        if (err || !_data.length) {
                            return self.fetched_rev_share(channel, null);
                        }

                        return self.fetched_rev_share(channel, _data[0]);
                    });
            })(self.channel_data[j], j);
}
```

Here is the warning being displayed:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 51 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
at EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
at EventEmitter.once (events.js:185:8)
at SkinClass.open (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:156:23)
at SkinClass.SkinCollection._open (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/collection.js:49:17)
at SkinClass.open (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:162:14)
at SkinClass.SkinCursor._open (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/cursor.js:28:25)
at SkinClass.open (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:162:14)
at SkinClass.(anonymous function) [as sort] (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:116:14)
at /Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/helpers/channel_earnings.js:61:18
at Query.loop_to_channels [as _callback] (/Users/ninz/Sites/freedom-node-backend/helpers/channel_earnings.js:70:7)
```

Comment: Did you get to know, how to get rid of this warning and what was the cause of it?

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya as far as I remembered, we ditched using mongodb in favor of aurora/mysql because of another requirement so I forgot the fix for this already. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are executing (I'm assuming it is because `self.channel_data` contains 51 keys) causes 51 listeners to be added to an [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter). In order to help prevent memory leaks, EventEmitters throw warnings when you add more than `n` listeners (10 by default) - which you did in this case.

In order to fix it, you need to set the EventEmitter max listener amount to more than 51 - lets say 75. [Here are the docs for that change](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n).

```
eventemitter.setMaxListeners(75);
```

I don't have enough experience with the Mongo driver to pinpoint where your `eventemitter` is, but thats the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js`, you can see at line 45 that they specifically set the max listeners to 50.

```
this._emitter.setMaxListeners(50);
```

What you can do is to globally change this, or just edit it yourself in the js file.

```
this._emitter.setMaxListeners(0);
```

0 removes the limit (as far as I know).